# Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker push Reason: exit status 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr, docker-push

I'm trying to build a pipeline that build and push docker images to ECR using buildspec for AWS CodeBuild. My project is multi containers microservices with docker-compose yaml file. I have enable Privileged mode for my CodeBuild, the pipeline is able login to AWS, build and tag the images but it's failing at docker push command with the following error:

```
[Container] 2023/02/21 17:45:38 Command did not exit successfully docker push $REPOSITORY_URL/service1:$TAG exit status 1
[Container] 2023/02/21 17:45:38 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/02/21 17:45:38 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker push $REPOSITORY_URL/service1:$TAG. Reason: exit status 1
```

My docker-compose.yaml file looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  service1:
    image: service1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Service1.API/Dockerfile

  service2:
    image: service2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service2.API/Dockerfile
```

My buildspec file looks like this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: latest
  pre_build:
    commands:
      # This Docker Image tag will have date, time and Codecommit version
      - TAG="$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S).$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | head -c 8)"
      # Check AWS CLI Version        
      - echo "Checking AWS CLI Version..."
      - aws --version
      # Login to ECR Registry 
      - echo "Logging in to Amazon ECR..."
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Docker build started on `date`"
      - echo "Building the Docker images..."
      - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
      - echo Tagging the Docker images...
      - docker tag service1:latest $REPOSITORY_URL/service1:$TAG
      - docker tag service2:latest $REPOSITORY_URL/service2:$TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      # Push Docker Image to ECR Repository
      - echo "Docker build completed on `date`"
      - echo "Pushing the Docker images to Amazon ECR..."
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URL/service1:$TAG
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URL/service2:$TAG
      - echo "Docker Push to ECR Repository Completed -  $REPOSITORY_URL:$TAG"          
      # Create Artifacts which we can use if we want to continue our pipeline for other stages
      - echo "Writing the image details to a file...""
      - echo {\"service1\":\"$REPOSITORY_URL/service1:$TAG\",\"service2\":\"$REPOSITORY_URL/service2:$TAG\"} > build.json
artifacts:
  files:
    - build.json
    - manifests/*
```

I have attached all necessary policies an permision to my codebuild service role, my policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:<ACCOUNT_ID>:repository/dev-repo"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr-public:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "sts:GetServiceBearerToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The log error is not clear enough and does not give head on what could be wrong, I have joined some answers to these similar questions to form my policy but it's still not working for me.

1. [AWS ECS CodePipeline build error REPOSITORY_URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758423/aws-ecs-codepipeline-build-error-repository-uri)
2. [docker push with AWS CodeBuild fails with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950091/docker-push-with-aws-codebuild-fails-with-exit-status-1)
3. [docker push with AWS CodeBuild fails with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950091/docker-push-with-aws-codebuild-fails-with-exit-status-1)

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems pretty clear to me:

```
Command did not exit successfully docker push $REPOSITORY_URL/service1:$TAG exit status 1
```

Your command is invalid, you're trying to push to a destination named ***$REPOSITORY_URL/service1:$TAG***.

You're setting TAG in the pre-build phase, but this is not the right way to do it, and anyway the correct syntax should be

```
export TAG="$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S).$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | head -c 8)"
```

Follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html) to write a correct buildspec.
At least, you're missing the env section with the properly variables setting.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, as both using 'export' and not using it seems pretty the same. I have actually echoed $TAG to see what it looks like for both cases and the values are the same thing. BTW I did as you suggested but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a multi container microservices application, I thought I could use a single ECR repository for both images, turned out this was the issue. So I solved this by making sure that each image has separate ECR repository and the image name must match the repository name.

Example:

```
docker tag service1:latest $REPOSITORY_URL:$TAG
```

$REPOSITORY_URL should be:

```
<ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/service1
```